# Objective-c protocol property attributes overridden in interface; best practice?

Tags: objective-c, properties, attributes, protocols

If you define a property with attributes in a protocol, e.g.:

```
@protocol ExampleProtocol <NSObject>

@property NSString * test0;

@property NSString * test1;

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString * test2;

@property (weak, atomic) NSString * test3;

@end
```

Then 'override' these attributes in the interface, e.g.:

```
@interface Example : SKLabelNode <ExampleProtocol>

@property NSString * test0; // No warnings

@property (strong, atomic) NSString * test1; // No warnings

@property (strong, atomic) NSString * test2; // Warns about both strong and atomic

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * test3; // Warns about both strong and atomic

@end
```

You get compiler warnings, not error, when the attributes don't match.

I am not an expert but looking at the assembly indicates to me that the attributes in the interface are the ones that 'win'.

Is it therefore best practice to omit attributes on protocol properties unless you know that they are always required as part of the protocol's contract?

Answer (score 0):

*Ignoring the fact that it is generally a bad idea™ to put property declarations in protocols, let alone weak properties.

The problem with overriding property declarations like this, or at least the compiler's beef with you overriding them, is that you're redeclaring the storage modifiers of the backing variables for that protocol (or what will be reified later by classes conforming to that protocol).  The compiler cannot, and frankly should not have to, guarantee which of the two modifiers it will ultimately end up generating code for, and so it emits a warning.  Weak variables versus strong variables are nontrivially convertible, and can be ambiguous at compile-time to anybody trying to use your code.  What the compiler can guarantee is that atomic string accessor that isnt throwing a warning.  All it takes is just generating a locally synchronized getter in the main class.

As you yourself mentioned, a protocol is akin to a contract.  There is no point in declaring properties in them because the `@property` directive indicates the manner in which to synthesize all that is necessary to create a new property on an *object*.  At most, what you've done is forced implementors to change their backing variables, at worst you've created the potential for bugs down the road.  Just declare setters and getters sans directive in a protocol, or make then actual properties of the implementing class.  It's highly unusual for a protocol to be this strictly readwrite anyhow.

Comment: I would argue that storage modifiers shouldn't be in a property declaration. A property is just a getter-setter pair, with no promises about how it is stored or even if there is a backing variable. Storage modifiers should only be in the synthesize directive, and a property may or may not be synthesized, but that's an implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, valuable opinions. I quite like the property declaration compared to method declarations because I find them clearer and they group the getter and setter into one line and ensure KVC. I think I will stop using attributes though because of the issues raised. Thanks again.